# Wordpress - Listing sub-menus in 2 columns - CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a edit CSS extension from the slim jetpack plugin for my wordpress project. Unfortunately it is placed on the internal server so I cant share the link with you.

The issue:  I have a round 30 sub-menus to present under the menu on the header. Decided that the best way would be  to use custom CSS to edit that specific menu instead of changing all the menus look.

So i followed the guide presented [here](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/wordpress-sub-menu-items-split-in-2-columns-the-easy-way/): 
added the **sub-menu-columns** as a custom CSS class on the desired menu
and added this to my CSS file:

```css
.sub-menu {
    width: 410px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

I am ended up with all the sub menus being 410px wide (instead of original 184px). And the sub-menus in the desired place are still in one column but simply have spaces on right and left sides.

I am new to CSS but it seems that the first .sub-menu declaration is wrongly placed here as it affects all the sub-menus. As well i am struggling to get 2 sub-menu items on the same row.

I kinda understand where are the "legs" growing from but it seems i am missing something here.

I searched for the similar cases but could not find clear explanations on this subject.
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

After some research i found that a
.sub-menu class
had clear: both; defined that caused the issues.

This the code i ended up which worked perfectly fine:

```css
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
 clear: initial;
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes here looking for a similar solution, here is what worked for me, on WordPress 5.7, theme [Chaplin](https://www.andersnoren.se/themes/chaplin/):

```css
@media (min-width: 999px) {
.submenu-columns>ul {
    width:50rem;
    }
.submenu-columns>ul>li {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    }
.submenu-columns>ul>li a {
    width:100%;
    }
.submenu-columns.odd>ul>li:last-child {
    width:100%;
    }
}
```